# Как сделать так, чтобы телеграмм-бот проверял правильность ввода и если ввод неправильный то он спрашивал заново пока ввод не будет правильным?

Tags: python, telebot

```
elif message.text == "Начать игру!":
    q = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Введите ставку: \n\nВаш баланс: {bal}")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(q, stavk)


def stavk(message):
    global stav
    stavka = int(message.text)
    if stavka <= 0 or stavka > bal:
        while stavka <= 0 or stavka > bal:
            w = bot.reply_to(message, "Неправильная ставка! Повторите: ")
            bot.register_next_step_handler(w, prov_stav)
            stavka = stav
        return stavka
    else:
        return stavka 


def prov_stav(message):
    stav = int(message.text)
    return stav
```

Answer (score -2):

Попробуйте так:

```py
def prov_stav():
    w = bot.reply_to(message, "Неправильная ставка! Повторите: ")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(w, stavk)

def stavk(message):
    stavka = int(message.text)
    if stavka <= 0 or stavka > bal:
        while stavka <= 0 or stavka > bal:
            prov_stay()
        return stavka
    else:
        return stavka
```